# При скачивании Pdf файла через DownloadManager скаченный файл видно только в родном проводнике

Tags: java, android

Я скачиваю файлы PDF через этот код.
Загрузка происходит .Но проблема  в том что скаченный файл видно только через родной проводник android. через любой другой включая даже просмотр через компьютер файла нет.
Помогает только перенос файла в родном проводнике с папки загрузки в папку загрузки. Только тогда файл становиться видимым.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.start_download, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(loadUrl);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                    request.setTitle("");
                    request.setDescription("Загрузка");
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

..

```
public class MainActivity2_3 extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadFile.Listener {

    LinearLayout root;
    RemotePDFViewPager remotePDFViewPager;
    Button btnDownload;
    PDFPagerAdapter adapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private Vibrator Vibro;


     public String loadUrl;

    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.exit__back)

                .setNeutralButton(R.string.refresh , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        recreate();

                    }
                })


                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                    {
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.remove("Url");
                        editor.apply();

                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2_3.this, MainActivity2_2.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }).create().show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2_3);

        cd =new ConnectionDetector(this);
        if(cd.isConnected())

        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.page_loading, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else

        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        loadUrl=(settings.getString("Url", ""));
        editor.apply();


              root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.remote_pdf_root);
              btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_download);


        onClick(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.close();
        }
    }

    public void onClick_download(View v) {
        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity2_3.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity2_3.this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.access_storage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }

        else
        {

            if(cd.isConnected())

            {
                if ( loadUrl.equals(""))
                {}

                else
                {


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.start_download, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(loadUrl);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                    request.setTitle("");
                    request.setDescription("Загрузка");
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);

                }

            }
            else

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }

        }
    }


    public void showDownloadButton() {
        btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideDownloadButton() {
        btnDownload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void updateLayout() {
        root.removeAllViewsInLayout();


        root.addView(progressBar,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        root.addView(btnDownload,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        root.addView(remotePDFViewPager,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String url, String destinationPath) {
        adapter = new PDFPagerAdapter(this, FileUtil.extractFileNameFromURL(url));
        remotePDFViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        updateLayout();
        showDownloadButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showDownloadButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int progress, int total) {}

    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Context ctx = this;
        final DownloadFile.Listener listener = this;
        remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(ctx, loadUrl, listener);
        remotePDFViewPager.setId(R.id.pdfViewPager);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить   `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name");`
Но как получить
 вместо  name мой
  request.setTitle("");